Accessing Windows app menu items via Robot+rpaframework
I'm automating some Windows app via rpaframework, using mostly functionality of RPA.Windows. I have a tasks file that works up to a point:
*** Settings ***
Library                             RPA.Windows

*** Variables ***

*** Tasks ***
Set Text Into Notepad Window
    Windows Run    Notepad
    Control Window      subname:Notepad
    Click    name:File
    Click    name:Save

It opens File menu just fine. But then "clicking" Save fails:
ElementNotFound: Element not found with locator 'name:Save'

Why is that? How can I fix it?

I ran your code (on my Win11 machine) and it did not return any errors. However, the code only highlighted the 'Save' button after Click    name:File but did not actually click it. Weirdly, when I used Double Click    name:Save, then the code clicked on the 'Save' button. Maybe its an issue that needs to be raised in Github?

Please set your log level to TRACE and check what the log says about a root element immediately before it executes Click    name:Save. My suspicion is that on your machine, the File menu opens an extra window; but you have set your Notepad window as the anchor window, which will then be used as the place to find name:Save.
